# React Native Run Android

Tags: javascript, android, ios, reactjs, react-native

Facing the issue with react native run-android.
I'm unable to start react app

```
Loading dependency graph, done.
error: bundling failed: Error: Plugin/Preset files are not allowed to export objects, only functions. In E:\react\udemy2\node_modules\babel-preset-expo\index.js
    at createDescriptor (E:\react\udemy2\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\config-descriptors.js:162:11)
    at items.map (E:\react\udemy2\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\config-descriptors.js:87:50)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at createDescriptors (E:\react\udemy2\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\config-descriptors.js:87:29)
    at createPresetDescriptors (E:\react\udemy2\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\config-descriptors.js:79:10)
    at presets (E:\react\udemy2\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\config-descriptors.js:61:19)
    at presets (E:\react\udemy2\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\config-descriptors.js:51:25)
    at mergeChainOpts (E:\react\udemy2\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\config-chain.js:308:26)
    at E:\react\udemy2\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\config-chain.js:271:7
 BUNDLE  [android, dev] ..\..\../index.js ░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░ 0.0% (0/1), failed.
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me when I got this error

Reason: Just like env is now @babel/env, react should be @babel/react and so you'll need to install

```
npm i @babel/preset-react
```

In .babelrc

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env","react"] 
}
```

Check if above helps you to get rid of that error if not then share your installed  babel packages version and babel config